# Kafka Cruise Control - NumValidWindows: (0/0) (NaN%), NumValidPartitions: 0/844 (0.000%)

Tags: apache-kafka

Need some help figuring out issues setting up kafka cruise control with kafka cluster with 3 brokers.

I was trying to set-up cruise control localhost(locally running kafka broker and cruise control) and was successful:

```
MonitorState: {state: RUNNING(1.000% trained), NumValidWindows: (1/1) (100.000%), NumValidPartitions: 138/138 (100.000%), flawedPartitions: 0}...}
```

But the issue is , when I started setting up on 3 broker Kafka 1.1 cluster, I am not seeing any progress:

```
{MonitorState: {**state: RUNNING(0.000% trained), NumValidWindows: (0/0) (NaN%), NumValidPartitions: 0/844 (0.000%)**, flawedPartitions: 0}, ExecutorState: {state: NO_TASK_IN_PROGRESS, finished/total leadership movements: 0/0}, AnalyzerState: {isProposalReady: false, ReadyGoals: []}}
```

Can some please help on this, if I am missing any configs here? in CC logs I am seeing:

```
[2018-05-23 15:27:51,733] INFO Collected 0 partition metric samples for 0 partitions. Total partition assigned: 844. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.monitor.sampling.SamplingFetcher)
[2018-05-23 15:27:51,733] INFO Collected 0 broker metric samples for 0 brokers. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.monitor.sampling.SamplingFetcher)
[2018-05-23 15:27:51,733] INFO Finished sampling in 5147 ms. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.monitor.sampling.MetricFetcherManager)
[2018-05-23 15:27:53,437] INFO Skipping best proposal precomputing because load monitor does not have enough snapshots. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.analyzer.GoalOptimizer)
[2018-05-23 15:28:23,438] INFO Skipping best proposal precomputing because load monitor does not have enough snapshots. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.analyzer.GoalOptimizer)
[2018-05-23 15:28:53,438] INFO Skipping best proposal precomputing because load monitor does not have enough snapshots. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.analyzer.GoalOptimizer)
[2018-05-23 15:29:23,438] INFO Skipping best proposal precomputing because load monitor does not have enough snapshots. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.analyzer.GoalOptimizer)
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the root cause. it was configuration fix. I have added below configuration into the Kafka server:

`server.properties:cruise.control.metrics.reporter.bootstrap.servers=0.0.0.0:9092`

That did the magic:
`{MonitorState: {state: RUNNING(20.000% trained), NumValidWindows: (1/1) (100.000%), NumValidPartitions: 124/124 (100.000%), flawedPartitions: 0}, ExecutorState: {state: NO_TASK_IN_PROGRESS, finished/total leadership movements: 0/0}, AnalyzerState: {isProposalReady: true, ReadyGoals: [NetworkInboundUsageDistributionGoal, CpuUsageDistributionGoal, PotentialNwOutGoal, NetworkInboundCapacityGoal, LeaderBytesInDistributionGoal, DiskCapacityGoal, ReplicaDistributionGoal, RackAwareGoal, TopicReplicaDistributionGoal, NetworkOutboundCapacityGoal, CpuCapacityGoal, DiskUsageDistributionGoal, NetworkOutboundUsageDistributionGoal, ReplicaCapacityGoal]}}`

Reason:  it was due to kafka was running on host IP not on localhost , above config helped to fix it